# jquery - call a function when page load with conditioning

Tags: jquery

I have a basic jquery code to hide and show the table, but I couldn't get it to work correctly.

So I have to code below and the table id "tblEstHr"

```
<script>
var funcToggleEstHrTable // define outside of Jquery
$(document).ready(function() {

    funcToggleEstHrTable = function(flag)
    {
        alert("toggle EstHR");
        if (flag == "1") 
        { 
            $("#tblEstHr").show()
        } else {
            $("#tblEstHr").hide()   
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Within the form, if I test this by click on this button below, it will work.

```
<input type="button" name="test" id="test" value="test" onClick="funcToggleEstHrTable('0')"/>
```

However, if I put this function in the if statement inside the form while page is loading, it is not working. like this

```
<% If Username = "ABC" %>
    <script>funcToggleEstHrTable('0');</script>

    <table id="tblEstHr">
        ...
```

Please help,
Thanks,

Comment: Since the script is in `.ready()`, it will only execute once the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: $(function(){funcToggleEstHrTable('0');}};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>funcToggleEstHrTable('0');</script> this needs to called on doc ready.
```

```html
<script>
var funcToggleEstHrTable // define outside of Jquery
$(document).ready(function() {

    funcToggleEstHrTable = function(flag)
    {
        alert("toggle EstHR");
        if (flag == "1") 
        { 
            $("#tblEstHr").show()
        } else {
            $("#tblEstHr").hide()   
        }
    }

});
</script>

<script>$(function(e){funcToggleEstHrTable('0');});</script>

    <table id="tblEstHr">
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $.ready in your first snippet, however you do need it in the code you are outputting with *<insert server-side language>*, or you can move it to after the table and again not need it.

```
function funcToggleEstHrTable (flag) {
    alert("toggle EstHR");
    if (flag == "1") { 
        $("#tblEstHr").show()
    } else {
        $("#tblEstHr").hide()   
    }
}
```

```
<% If Username = "ABC" %>


    <table id="tblEstHr">
        ...
    </table>
    <script>funcToggleEstHrTable('0');</script>
```